# Deploy a private image inside minikube on linux

Tags: minikube

I am starting to use kubernetes/Minikube to deploy my application which is currently running on docker containers.

Docker version:19.03.7
Minikube version: v1.25.2

From what I read I gather that first of all I need to build my frontend/backend images inside minikube.

The image is available on the server and I can see it using:

> $ docker image ls

The first step, as far as I understand, is to use the "docker build" command:

> $docke build -t my-image .

However, the dot at the end, so I understand, means it is looking for a Dockerfile in the curretn directoy, and indeed I get an error:

> unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat
> /home/dep/k8s-config/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

So, where do I get this dockerfile for the "docker build" to succeed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My missunderstanding...
I have the Dockefile now, so I should put it anywhere and use docker build from there.